# How to extract phonetic language from the web with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, extract, phonetics

I'm trying to extract the phonetic spelling of a web dictionary entry.
Specifically, this dictionary [AVL-DNV](http://www.avl.gva.es/lexicval/?paraula=perol)

Is there any way of working with phonetic language in Python and extracting the phonetic spelling from a web?
My goal would be to extract something like this [peɾɔ́l].

Answer (score 1):

For extracting things from HTML documents you can use [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup). For example:

```py
import warnings

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

url = "https://www.avl.gva.es/lexicval/?paraula=perol"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

ph = [tag.text for tag in soup.select(".trfonetica")]
print(ph[-1])
```

Prints:

```
[peɾɔ́l]
```